# Linking with cygwin1.dll while building with mingw32?

Tags: c++, dll, cygwin, cross-platform, mingw

I wish to port a Linux C++ application to Windows with the minimum possible effort (i.e. no code modifications at all, and no entirely new build system).

The application is mainly doing API calls to `SDL` and `OpenGL`, which both are available on Windows. However, it also uses `POSIX` functionality such as ptys, which are preventing me from using the `mingw32` toolchain.

`Cygwin`, or, more precisely, `cygwin1.dll`, implements the whole `POSIX` API and internally translates it to `Win32`. I understand that `Cygwin` also comes with its own compiler suite, but to my understanding it is impossible to directly make calls to `Win32` or other Windows libraries (such as `SDL` or `OpenGL`).

Hence, my idea is to build the project with `mingw32` (which is conveniently also available as a cross-compiler on most distros), but in addition also link with `cygwin1.dll`. I am, however, getting suspicious by the fact that nobody on the internet seems to have tried this, and the seeming unavailability of the cygwin compiler on Linux.

So my question would be:

- Is this a legitimate idea, or will everything fail horribly even if I manage to hack it together?
- What's the legitimate way of doing it (where do I get the cygwin headers and dll file)?

Licensing is not an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot possibly work.  The key issue is that there are two different and incompatible versions of the C runtime library (CRT) -- Cygwin's GNU library (glibc) and Microsoft's C runtime.  The MinGW toolchain uses the Microsoft CRT, while the Cygwin GCC toolchain uses the Cygwin CRT.

Each of these two CRTs is implemented differently.  Take the `malloc()` function, for example.  Both CRTs implement `malloc()` differently, perhaps by allocating virtual memory from the OS with `VirtualAlloc()` and then divying it up accordingly in their own manner.  If somehow you had a program which loaded both CRTs into it and you called `malloc()` from one CRT but then tried to `free()` it in another, it would crash horribly, because each CRT doesn't know how the underlying data structures work in the other.

So even if you managed to cobble together something here and got everything to compile and link without errors, it would still crash at runtime in "impossible" ways because of this fundamental incompatibility.

Now, what's the correct way to do things here?  You need to decide which CRT you want to use.  The Microsoft CRT does not support many POSIX features, so if you don't want to rewrite your code to avoid all of those missing POSIX features, you must use the Cygwin CRT, and you must use it for **all** code in your project (all source files, all static libraries, all DLLs, etc.).

Your understanding about Win32 is wrong -- you *can* make calls to the raw Win32 API from Cygwin programs.  The Cygwin GCC toolchain even comes with its own `<windows.h>` header file.  There are no restrictions against calling functions like `CreateFile`, `VirtualAlloc`, etc.

For other libraries you're using such as SDL and OpenGL, you need versions of those libraries which are compiled against the same CRT which you're targeting.  If you have the source code for the libraries, then you can just compile them yourselves.

[Here are instructions](http://www.libsdl.org/extras/win32/cygwin/README.txt) for compiling SDL for Cygwin.  For OpenGL, there are a bunch of packages you can install via Cygwin setup for getting OpenGL header files and libraries, e.g. the `libEGL-devel`, `libGL-devel`, `libGLU-devel`, `libglut-devel`, and `libGLw-devel` packages.

Comment: While I understand your point, I believe `malloc` is not a very suitable example, as `free`ing memory allocated in a different library always is extremely bad style, as it MAY lead to undefined behaviour even if all libraries were compiled the same way.

Comment: @mic_e: It may be bad style, but it has perfectly defined behavior as long as the libraries involved document their policies.  If you want a different example, think about stdio `FILE*` pointers.  Many libraries take a `FILE*` parameter in function calls; if that `FILE*` was `fopen`'ed from a different CRT than the one the library uses, then it's almost certainly going to crash.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend against it. You will definitely hit binary incompatibilities and many other subtle issues during linking stage and most importantly at runtime. Every toolchain has its purpose, so use what fits your requirements better.

- Willing to give up platform dependent functionality (direct usage of POSIX in your code)? Then eliminate it and go for **[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)**.
- No? You have no choice, but to use Cygwin and the GCC toolchain that comes with it. By the way they recently introduced 64-bit (x64) version of Cygwin (and the accompanying GCC toolchain) which works very well.

To me both approaches look fine. Cygwin's translation overhead is really minimal, and you don't have to distribute the whole Cygwin for your application to work, but just the runtime DLLs. Nevertheless, personally, I think that modern cross-platform applications should struggle to be truly cross-platform and not use *directly* such low-level API as POSIX as this is actually a flaw of the application in the first place which claims to be cross-platform. And thank god, today we have plenty of modern and high-quality libraries to help us with that. For instance, in my projects I always stick to the first approach, and so far I have to admit that it's always possible, but sometimes just requires some hassle which you shouldn't be scared of as it will definitely pay off in the future.